# Why do I get an error 400 with one constructed URL and not with the other one?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, feed

You can access questions with tags by link construction:

> `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3]`

But when I combine a lot of tags I get an error 400 (invalid URL). In my case the URL length was 755 characters.

But when I use the link

> `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3]&sort=newest`

then the page is loaded, even though I used the same big set of tags (and this time we have 768 characters).

When I pass the link to my RSS reader (with `%20` instead of a space)

> `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=[tag1]%20or%20[tag2]%20or%20[tag3]`

all data was properly loaded with no errors (908 characters this time).

Is there some bug/limitation to the length of the first link construction (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[tags]) that does not apply to second method (https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=[tags])?

Comment: It's very likely that the URL mapper (which redirects you to the second format "under the hood") has a max limit somehow. Either it has a fail-safe that is enabled above a certain URL length (for performance reasons or whatnot), or the regular expression engine simply doesn't match more than a certain number of characters, resulting in a failed match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs of the form

```
http://example.com/tagged/foo+bar+baz
```

have a "path length limit" of about ~260 characters

URLs of the form

```
http://example.com/?tags=foo+bar+baz
```

do not.

edit: we can now change this, as we've switched to .NET 4.0 which supports the [HttpRuntimeSection.MaxUrlLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxurllength.aspx) property -- for now I am relaxing it to **512** characters, from the default of 260.

see related SO question about general practical length of URLs at:
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url)

Comment: Re-he-he-heally!  I wonder what is so special about 260 chars.  I mean, shouldn't it be 255 chars?  `MAX_PATH` in windows is also 260 chars.  I wonder if this is different on linux-based systems.