# Invalid URL when using many tags? (2010.8.25.1 on SO)

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

Hi,

I used to monitor all eclipse related tags:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=eclipse~&sort=newest&pagesize=50

That generate (after a refresh) the full address:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse+or+eclipse-plugin+or+eclipse-rcp+or+eclipse-cdt+or+eclipselink+or+eclipse-pde+or+eclipse-pdt+or+eclipse-3.4+or+eclipse-3.5+or+eclipse-plugin-dev+or+eclipse-wtp+or+eclipse-jdt+or+eclipse-3.6+or+eclipse-3.3+or+eclipse-3.2+or+eclipseme+or+eclipse-templates+or+eclipse-api+or+eclipse-3.5.1+or+eclipse-rap?sort=newest&pagesize=50

Two questions:

1/ I never notices the '+' (%2b). Before today there were only spaces (%20) between the tags and the '`or`'

2/ this full address generates a `HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.` (FireFox 3.6.8)
Do you know why?
Such addresses (even ones much longer) used to be served without issue before today.

Bonus question:

An address like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=clearcase~%20or%20git&sort=newest&pagesize=50

generates the (working actually) full address:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clearcase+or+clearcase-remote-client+or+or+git?sort=newest&pagesize=50

Why the two '`or`' between `clearcase-remote` and `git` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here:
[Why do I get an error 400 with one constructed URL and not with the other one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/why-do-i-get-an-error-400-with-one-constructed-url-and-not-with-the-other-one/48192#48192)

And here:
[Bug with single character tags in urls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/bug-with-single-character-tags-in-urls/4424#4424)

Manually combining `or` and tag wildcards basically isn't supported at the moment, so use at your own risk. There are some boolean logic issues because we don't support parens to disambiguate.

Comment: Strange. Those were working perfectly before today. Any plan to restore this service?

Comment: @vonc construct the url in the alternative manner specified at the first link as a workaround for now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/?tags=clearcase+or+ccrc or http://stackoverflow.com/questions?tags=clearcase+or+ccrc or http://stackoverflow.com/?tags=clearcase+or+ccrc don't work (any display all 800K + question). I must be missing something obvious in those urls...

Comment: Got it: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=...** should work just fine, while avoiding any length limitation.

Comment: @vonc they've been broken in this fashion for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the UI needs to stop generating links to topics that lead to server errors. If I click a link and it 400's on a page that was not generated through any real trickery, there's something broken in the system. Look at the length of the generated url and prune it if it's too long, or send us to a "try a narrower search" page, or something.